# create a logo with css3

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to create a Vodafone logo with css like this one: 
[image]

I know some people are able to draw anything with css. I can't figure out how to make the tear drop shape. This is what I have as far as now:

```css
#logoMain {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px #999 inset;
  position: relative;
}

#logoMainafter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 12%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}

#logoInside {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 24px;
  background-color: #fe0000;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px #a80000 inset;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="logoMain">
    <div id="logoInside"></div>
    <div id="logoMainafter"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone give me any ideas how to create this unusual shape?

Comment: Just my first idea: how about flipping (horizontally) a single quote (') or a comma (,) (possibly using a specific font that looks closest to the "teardrop") and using that as a basis for the rest?

Comment: here's a yin yang, which is kinda pretty similar, have a play! http://coursesweb.net/css/yin-yang-css_cs

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.bchanx.com/logos-in-pure-css-demo) showcase will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since anybody is answering, here you have a draft to begin with

CSS

```
#logoMain {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px #999 inset ;
    position: relative;
}

#logoMainafter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 12%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}

#logoInside {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 24px;
    background-color: #fe0000;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px #a80000 inset;
    z-index: 23;
    position: absolute;
}

#logoMain:after {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 57px;
    /* background-color: green; */
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: -19px 17px 0px 14px #e80000;
    clip: rect(0px, 12px, 63px, -110px);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3w7y/5/)

Comment: Works great. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3w7y/8/). However it's not 100% original. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: looks quite good. May be better adding some depth with dual box-shadows http://jsfiddle.net/n3w7y/9/

Answer (score 6):

For more complex shapes I'd look at using [d3js](http://d3js.org/) or [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and the `svg` element with css backing it. Take a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3094619). There is alot of other examples on the same site of complex shapes you can draw with CSS with a little help from JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best use of your time, drawing this in CSS. Use a graphics editor that is made for it and export it to SVG or any other picture format. The pain you need to go to code this is not worth it.